# Flutter: firebase messaging notifications can't play sound but it requested in code

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implement firebase messaging for my flutter project and request both sound and badge permissions:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
  alert: true,
  badge: true,
  sound: true,
);
print(settings.authorizationStatus);// Result: AuthorizationStatus.authorized
```

I requested sound, badge permission, but it doesn't apply in app settings and I have to do it manually:

[image: firebase messaging sound]

Tested on Android 11.

My firebase notifications can't play sound by default and every single user need to turn this on.
Why this happen? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I could see 2 problems.

### **1. Did you enabled the sound in notifications?**

When you send the notification payload, you need to include `"sound": "default"` to let notification sound play. You can also edit "default" if you want to use another sound. Example:

```json
{
    "to" : "<TokenOfDevice>",
    "notification" : {
      "body"  : "<NotificationMessage>",
      "title" : "<NotificationTitle>",
      "sound" : "default"
    }
  }
```

### **2. Have you checked on other OS?**

From your screenshot, it seems that your phone uses MIUI Os, which is heavily edited Android that already caused some troubles with notifications, power saving options....

If you could check on a "normal" AOSP Android, you'll know if it's a your software problem or not.

Comment: 1. Yes, It's about "Permission" and when sound permission is off, no notification can play sound
2. No, but there is no problem when I create notification channel for local notifications

Comment: Maybe the plugin or the code you're using for requesting the permission need some specific parameters to pass to the system to let it know you want sound with notifications

Comment: I did, indeed. In fact, I never used firebase directly to request permission, always used third party plugins that has more options available. So I suggested you to check if requestPermission require other options, other than that in OP. Or maybe you can follow my advice and use another plugin to manage device permissions, its your choice. There's no need to be sarcastic with that rethorical question, I'm here to help you.